# Changed the user password, but now I can't access my encrypted folder

Tags: lubuntu, encryption, ecryptfs

I changed my user password, but now I can't enter my encrypted folder when I login, I need to type `ecryptfs-mount-private` and type in the old password.

I changed it from `System Tools->Users and Groups`.

If I change my user password back to the old password, it starts working automatically again.

How do I manually change the encrypted folder's password to be my new password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by manually re-wrapping the pass-phrase after reading [this link](http://unixtitan.net/main/2010/11/16/annoyance-changing-password-with-ecryptfs/):

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

It’ll prompt you for your old password, and you can enter a new one afterwards.